# datepicker : error using french datepicker

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I want to display the datepicker in french and I included the cdn of the local

this is my code

```
   <html>
   <head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.fr.min.js">
        </script>
    </head>
                            
                            
    <body>
   <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
   <div class='input-group date' id='datepicker'>
   <input type='text' class="form-control" />
   <span class="input-group-addon">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
                                    
     $('.datepicker').datepicker({
      language: 'fr'})
      });
      </script>
      </body>
      </html>
```

and it gives me 2 errors

***first error***

[image]

***second error***

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with bootstrap but I'm pretty sure you simply included a locale file here. You need to include both the actual base datepicker.js file (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js) *and* the desired locale script.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the main datepicker too. Also I've added the missing `datepicker` class to the input and then the following snippet works.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.datepicker').datepicker({
    language: 'fr'
  })
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.fr.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="input-group date" id="datepicker">
      <!-- I've added the datepicker class, which you are using in your jQuery -->
      <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this library:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.13/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.13/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.13/js/messages/messages.fr-fr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="gj-clear-both"></div>
<div class="gj-margin-top-10">
    <input id="datepicker" width="276" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var datepicker, config;
  config = {
    locale: 'de-de',
    uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4'
  };
  $(document).ready(function () {
    datepicker = $('#datepicker').datepicker(config);
      config.locale = 'fr-fr';
      datepicker.destroy();
      datepicker = $('#datepicker').datepicker(config);
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link href="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.13/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.13/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.13/js/messages/messages.fr-fr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="gj-margin-top-10">
        <input id="datepicker" width="276" />
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>


<!-- end snippet -->
```